# request to server node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am learning about requests in node. I have created simple server

```
var http=require("http");
var fs=require("fs");
http.createServer(function(req,res){


    switch(req.url){
        case '/redirect' :
            res.writeHead({"Location ":'/'});
            res.end();
            break;

        case '/form.html' :
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            req.setEncoding("utf-8");
            var ws=fs.createReadStream("form.html")
            var body="";
            ws.pipe(body);      
            res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
            break;

        default:
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": 'text/plain'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            url:req.url,
            method:req.method,
            headers:req.headers
        }));

    }

}).listen(4001)
```

and request script

```
var request=require("request");
var inspect = require("util").inspect;

request('http://localhost:4001/form.html',function(err,res,body){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(inspect({
        err:err,
        res:{
            statusCode:res.statusCode
        },
        body:JSON.parse(body)
    }))
});
```

If i understood it correctly (logic behind requests) = 
1)the request script makes request(default get) to the server
2)The server script will notice request , and deterime what to do by request.url , here we are making request on /form.html
3) Server script will do /form/html case = put header into response, create read Stream and send the value into response
4) The response is sent into request script where it is represented by body argument in callback function
5) The script now do adction in callback function = console.log the response.

form.html contains simple htmp form , but why the output of request script is

```
{ err: null,
  res: { statusCode: 200 },
  body:
   { url: '/form.html',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { host: 'localhost:4001', connection: 'close' } } }
```

and not (in body) the text code that contains form.html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do in the `form.html` branch of your switch, but if you're just trying to serve the `form.html` file, you can do this:

```
    case '/form.html' :
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        var ws = fs.createReadStream("form.html");
        ws.pipe(res);
        break;
```

This will serve the contents of the local file `form.html` to the browser.

Comment: sorry, that was my typo writing the code here , the code i am executing contains form.html , edited q

Comment: @Johnyb - rewrote my answer.